# Simple variable understanding question

Tags: functions, soft-question

A function $f \colon X \to Y$ is a rule which assigns to each element $x \in X$ a unique element $y \in Y$.

I don't understand what it is meant by *each element $x$*. If it was “all $x$” or “each $x$” that would make sense to me.

Comment: Just to let you know, your question was very quickly edited and downvoted since your writing quality was not very high. If you want your posts to be better received on this site, consider using complete sentences and learning basic LaTeX.

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{cases}a&\text{if}~x=1\\b&\text{if}~x=2\\a&\text{if}~x=3\end{cases}$ is an example of a simple function with domain $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and codomain $Y=\{a,b,c,d\}$.  By "assigns to each element $x\in X$ a unique element $y\in Y$" we mean that each of the elements in $X$ (*in this case $1,2,3$*) can be used as "inputs" and we get out an "output" and specifically if we use a specific input, like $1$, we always get a consistent output (*in this example $a$*).

Comment: There's no difference in meaning between "each $x$" and "each element $x$". I think "each" is better than :"all" since the latter could be misunderstood as assigning the same $y$ to every $x$.

Comment: What's the difference between "each element x" and "each x"? Why does one confuse you and the other doesn't.  They seem exactly the same to me. I wouldn't understand what "all x" meant in this instance.  BTW/FWIW And would *definitely* not use the word "unique".  That seems to imply all the y values are different for each x value which is certain *NOT* the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"each element $x$" is the same thing as "each $x$". The word "element" is just to clarify that the symbol $x$ represents an element of the set $X$. In math it is common to write things like "the variable $a$", "the function $f$", "the curve $C$", and so on.

Here is the rule (definition of function) rewritten:

> A function $f : X \to Y$ is a rule such that: For all $x \in X$, we can assign $x$ an element $y \in Y$. We also write $y = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

What aras said:

But I'm one-upping his rewritten rule to emphasize a few things:

> A function $f:X→Y$ is a rule such that: For each distinct $x∈X$, there is a specific $y\in Y$ which we consistently assign to that particular $x$.

My point being that for each and every $x_{\alpha} \in X$, then $y_{\alpha} = f(x_{\alpha})$ will always exists and will be consistent.  (In other words, we can't have $f(6) = 7$ sometimes and then some other times have $f(6)=5$.)

Also it is important to not that i) although each $x$ has $y$ assigned to it, it does *not* have to be the case that every $y$ has an $x$ assigned to it and ii) although every $x$ has a $y$ assigned to it, the $y$s do not need to be different.  It will be possible for two different $x_{\alpha}, x_{\beta}$ to be assigned to the same $y$.  (In other words, it is possible to have $f(6) = 5$ and $f(7) = 5$.)